# Making android:windowBackground as @null by overriding the theme makes the view to repeat

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-theme, android-fullscreen, android-background

I recently moved one of my activities(starting with a blank activity in Android Studio) to a full screen activity. Earlier, my activity looked like this.
[image]
I have few custom views inside my layout. To make my activity full screen, I just created a new full screen activity using the option in Android Studio and copied my code to the new activity. I noticed that the newly created full screen activity generated a theme overriding the application theme and then assigns this theme to the activity. The generated theme is as follows:

```
<style name="FullscreenTheme" parent="MyDefaultTheme">
<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/FullscreenActionBarStyle</item>
<item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
<item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
<item name="metaButtonBarStyle">?android:attr/buttonBarStyle</item>
<item name="metaButtonBarButtonStyle">?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="FullscreenActionBarStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
<item name="android:background">@color/black_overlay</item>
    </style>
```

The problem I face is that the item

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
```

causes the activity view to be rendered like this:

[image]

If I comment that line in the new theme (or give it a color), everything seems to be working fine. I read few articles like [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.es/2009/03/window-backgrounds-ui-speed.html) to understand this but I am still not clear what is happening in my case. Any explanations for this issue?

Also, I do not see any utility of

```
<style name="FullscreenActionBarStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/colorBackgroundLT</item>
</style>
```

Can anybody explain this as well?